# Why does this return 42 instead of 682?

Tags: c

Working with bits in C.  I am trying to create a function that looks for a specific string of bits in a larger bit string.  My thinking was to compare the two using the & operator, then shifting the string left and repeating.  If the operator returns the larger number (because no bits should change), the pattern has been found.  Unfortunately, that seems to be a flawed method, since what I have narrowed down to is that when this happens it in fact returns the smaller string, throwing what I thought I knew into doubt.

I suppose my guess is that the zeroes in front aren't in fact added when doing this operation, but i'm wary of rationalizing the wrong theory in my coding, so here I am.  Please explain, none of the resources I have found really address what is going on here.  Thanks in advance.

```
int main (void)
{
    unsigned int x = 682;   //      1010101010
    unsigned int pattern = 42; //       101010
    unsigned int temp;

    temp = x & pattern;
    printf("%i\n", temp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&` returns the common bits: (101010 --> 42)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Comment: What output did it give? What did you expect instead?

Comment: @Jerry Singh I think that during more than five years of presence here you should already learn how the bit-wise operator & works.

Comment: @ David - Gotcha, I figured they would fill in the leading zeroes.  I guess I could shift it left and go in reverse, though methinks that might not be the best method.  Thanks though.

Comment: @ wikipedia.  The wikipedia article shows several examples where they have leading zeroes added in.

Comment: @Vlad Hi vlad ive been teaching myself as a hobby and took a few years off.  You can follow my progress pretty closely (since you're interested), though I cannot fathom why you would weigh in with that

Comment: @Useless  was looking for 682, but was getting 42.  David addressed it though, now i gots to figure some other way

Comment: @JerrySingh Usually learning of programming starts from learning of internal representations of data and with bit operations on them.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow sorry vlad i think i was a little too sensitive there.  bits is closer to the end of the my book, i have no cs background

Answer (score 1):

Because `&` compares the bits in bitwise order. For each pair of bits it will return 1 if both are 1 otherwise 0. The 42 in binary has an implicit set of zeros in front of it.

The comparison is

```
0000101010
1010101010
-----------
0000101010
```

Comment: oh ffs this site makes me hate myself.  I guess I should be using the XOR instead